# How do I handle onChange of objects inside an array (React State)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, setstate

community,

I'm trying to build a table where its rows are rendered based on an array of objects:

```
this.state = {
  tableContent: [
    { 
      id: this.state.tableContent.length,
      firstname:"",
      lastname:""
    },
    ...
  ]
```

Each row displays one object. (2 columns in this case, n rows)
Each cell is also an input field, so users can manipulate the table:

```
<tbody>
  {this.state.tableContent.map((row) => {
    return(
      <tr key={row.id}>
        <td><input value={row.firstname} onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange}> </input></td>
        ...
      </tr>
    )
  })}
</tbody>
```

I want each cell / input field to display the change when the user changes the input value and as such the state. Because I'm prepopulating the input field with `value={row.firstname}` I need to define an `onChange` handler function that changes the state/value of the target object's `firstname`property.

So how does my `onChange` handler function look like?
I tried using spreads, but to no avail so far...

Some thoughts:
Using the standard procedure doesn't work because I have a nested state (Array of objects):

```
handleChange = (event) => { this.setState({ firstname: event.target.value }) }
```

Trying to use the spread operator results in some weird mess as well:
(this code here is somewhat wrong: maybe you can fix it?)

```
handleFirstNameChange = (event) => {
    const {tableContent} = {...this.state};
    const currentState = tableContent;
    const { firstname, value } = event.target;
    currentState[0] = value;
    this.setState({ tableContent: currentState});
  }
```

I appreciate any help!

edit:
The code below seems to nearly work. (thanks @Nikhil ) However now, whenever the user types into the input field, every letter they type will replace the existing letter / value of 'row.firstname'. Also, state doesn't refresh automatically so only the last-typed letter would show up / persist. What I need the input field to have is a functionality just like any casual input field.
event.persist(); seems to be needed to keep the event value.

```
handleFirstNameChange = (id, event) => {
    event.persist(); 
    this.setState(prevState => {
      tableContent : prevState.tableContent.forEach((row) => {
        if(row.id === id) { row.firstname = event.target.value}
      })
    })
  }
```

input looks like this:

```
onChange={(event) => this.handleWNRChange(row.id,event)}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you elaborate on what you mean by "how does my onChange handler look like"? What is it that you are attempting to do? What does it do now? What did you expect instead?

Comment: What do you want to do when the input's value changes? Do you have a draft of the `handleFirstNameChange` yet? If you do, can you post that as well?

Comment: @Jason I added some drafts, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The question communicates your intention very well now!

Comment: I don't have the chance to post an answer now, but I think this section of React's documentation will help you out: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers. Also, be wary of the fact that the firstname property is being used as a key, but it will be changed by the input. This will probably cause unexpected effects :)! You'll either want each array item to have an id that you can use as a key, or if the order of the elements stays the same, you can just pass the index as the key (`map((row, index) =>`

Comment: Are the firstnames and lastname unique? How are you identifying the entries in the `tableContent` object? If "john" (`firstname`) changes, how do you know which "john" if they're not unique? Maybe you need to have an `id` key value?

Comment: @Jason I edited  it to use `.id`, thanks.

Comment: @Swen Can you add a jsfiddle link?

Comment: thanks @cubrr that is indeed helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this would work.

```js
const handleFirstNameChange = (id, event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {tableContext} = this.state;

    const myRowIndex = tableContext.findIndex((row) => row.id === id);
    tableContext[myRowIndex].firstname = event.target.value;

    this.setState({ tableContext });
}
```

This should be all you need. Just assign this method to the `onChange` of the `input` element. Like so:

```
onChange={(event) => this.handleFirstNameChange(row.id, event)}
```

Comment: Is `event.prevent` present? I would've thought that it's `preventDefault`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! Utilizing `.findIndex()`  solved it!

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help

```
{this.state.tableContent.map((row, index) => {
    return(
      <tr key={row.firstname}>
        <td><input value={row.firstname}
             onChange={(event)=>this.handleFirstNameChange(event, index)> </input></td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
}

handleFirstNameChange(event, index){
  this.setState((prevState => {
      tableContent : prevState.tableContent.forEach((row,i)=>{
        if(index === i) row.firstname = event.target.value
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! It nearly works. The proper field is updated. The only issues here are that whenever the user types into the input field, every letter they type will replace the existing letter / value of `row.firstname`. Also, state doesn't refresh automatically so only the last-typed letter would show up / persist. 
What I need is a functionality just like any other input field.

Comment: @SwenSchäferjohann Did you try with the key being `id` or an index? Notice that this example has `key={row.firstname}`